# python list intersection of several arrays

Tags: python

I want to intersect several(e.g. 3) lists.

```
a = ["a", "b", "c"]
b = ["d", "e", "f"]
c = ["g", "h", "i"]
```

There is an `intersect1d` method from `numpy`, but it accepts only 2 arrays per call, so, that is not that comfortable to use. Are their any methods, which accepts a bunch of lists at once?

Comment: Just convert to `set` and use the `&` operator- for example: `list(set(a)&set(b)&set(c))`. However, the intersection for your example is an empty set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had your lists in a `list`, you could do the following:

```
a = ["a", "b", "c"]
b = ["a", "e", "f"]
c = ["a", "h", "i"]

lists = [a, b, c]
intersection = list(reduce(lambda u, v: u&v, (set(x) for x in lists)))
print(intersection)
#['a']
```

Answer (score 1):

Intersect works with Sets and uses & to perform the operation. As it sits, you will return an empty set. If you change your lists a little, you can see it work.

```
a = ["a", "b", "c"]
b = ["d", "a", "f"]
c = ["g", "h", "a"]

set(a) & set(b) & set(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my preferred syntax:

```
a = ["a", "b", "c"]
b = ["a", "e", "f"]
c = ["a", "h", "i"]

set.intersection(*map(set, (a, b, c)))

# {'a'}
```